# Again membership_id error in manual membership

Tags: civimember

After upgrading to 5.41.2 on Wordpress 5.8.1 I still have the problem with manual add a new member.

```
ott 04 14:42:55  [error] 
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
  "message" => "Mandatory key(s) missing from params array: membership_id"
  "code" => null
  "exception" => CiviCRM_API3_Exception {#29193
    -extraParams: array:6 [
      "fields" => array:1 [
        0 => "membership_id"
      ]
      "error_code" => "mandatory_missing"
      "entity" => "MembershipPayment"
      "action" => "create"
      "is_error" => 1
      "error_message" => "Mandatory key(s) missing from params array: membership_id"
    ]
    #message: "Mandatory key(s) missing from params array: membership_id"
    #code: 0
    #file: "/home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php"
    #line: 134
    trace: {
      /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php:134 {
        › if (is_array($result) && !empty($result['is_error'])) {
        ›   throw new CiviCRM_API3_Exception($result['error_message'], CRM_Utils_Array::value('error_code', $result, 'undefined'), $result);
        › }
      }
      /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Member/BAO/Membership.php:2512 { …}
      /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/custom_php/CRM/Member/Form/Membership.php:1324 { …}
      /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/custom_php/CRM/Member/Form/Membership.php:881 { …}
      /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:526 { …}
      /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php:152 { …}
      /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php:119 { …}
      /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203 { …}
      /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103 { …}
      /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:352 { …}
      /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Member/Page/Tab.php:314 { …}
      /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Member/Page/Tab.php:384 { …}
      /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:313 { …}
      /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
      /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
      /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1178 { …}
      /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:292 { …}
      /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:316 { …}
      /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-includes/plugin.php:484 { …}
      /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-admin/admin.php:259 { …}
    }
  }
]
```

The custom php is not relevant: the problem is identical with original file (the custom is very simple and very localized)
I do more investigation and for me it is strange is the variable is not set and the https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2431 I understand that the problem is related to the form which pass the data. I have printed the values:

```
ott 04 15:43:46  [info] $$this->_params = Array
(
    [hidden_custom] => 1
    [hidden_custom_group_count] => Array
        (
            [] => 1
        )

    [qfKey] => CRMMemberFormMembership2dowfisuhgsgcs4wo0c4kw08occ0wswo0c0swcw00cc0kc8gkg_9712
    [entryURL] => https://staging.grag.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&amp;q=civicrm%2Fmember%2Fadd&amp;page=CiviCRM&amp;reset=1&amp;action=add&amp;context=standalone
    [join_date] => 2021-10-04
    [start_date] => 
    [end_date] => 
    [price_set_id] => 
    [contact_id] => 798
    [max_related] => 
    [membership_type_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [num_terms] => 1
    [source] => 
    [campaign_id] => 
    [status_id] => 
    [is_override] => 
    [status_override_end_date] => 
    [record_contribution] => 1
    [total_amount] => 30,00
    [receive_date] => 2021-10-04 15:43:00
    [payment_instrument_id] => 5
    [trxn_id] => 
    [contribution_status_id] => 1
    [financial_type_id] => 2
    [soft_credit_type_id] => 
    [soft_credit_contact_id] => 
    [from_email_address] => 2
    [receipt_text] => 
    [MAX_FILE_SIZE] => 1073741824
    [discountcode] => 
)


ott 04 15:43:46  [info] $this->_mode is not set

ott 04 15:43:46  [info] $$params = Array
(
    [tax_amount] => 0
    [total_amount] => 30.00
    [contact_id] => 798
    [status_id] => 
    [source] => 
    [is_override] => 0
    [status_override_end_date] => 
    [campaign_id] => 
    [custom] => Array
        (
        )

    [exclude_is_admin] => 1
    [contribution_recur_id] => 
    [payment_instrument_id] => 5
    [trxn_id] => 
    [contribution_status_id] => 1
    [check_number] => 
    [receive_date] => 2021-10-04 15:43:00
    [card_type_id] => 
    [pan_truncation] => 
    [financial_type_id] => 2
    [contribution_source] => Ordinario Iscrizione: Registrazione Offline (di Giorgio Mazzacurati)
    [lineItems] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [processPriceSet] => 1
)
```

But doesn't see any membership_id, could you help to solve the problem and set this value?

Comment: We're seeing this issue too in 5.45 and WordPress 5.8.3. We use a Price Set for our Memberships, so maybe that is the issue. Can you clarify what action you took to resolve/get around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After a long debug analysis I understand that the problem is related to missing linenumber associated to the membership type. I solved saving every records with a price without . (Maybe it is enough to save)